# Transition level has to be readback and what about transition altitude? is it also required to be readback by the pilot?

Tags: air-traffic-control, pilots

These are the readback requirements, source by https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Read-back_or_Hear-back 
a) ATC route clearances;
b) clearances and instructions to enter, land on, take off from, hold short of, cross or backtrack on any runway; and
c) runway-in-use, altimeter settings, SSR codes, level instructions, heading and speed instructions and, whether issued by the controller or contained in Automatic Terminal Information Service (ATIS) broadcasts, **transition levels**.

Comment: I don't understand your question here, are you asking whether a pilot needs a clearance to go above transition level, or notify ATC when they reach transition level?

Comment: I asked that transition level has to be readback by the pilot and I wonder that transition altitude is also valid for this?

Comment: Or, is your question about having to read back altitudes stemming from not understanding the word “level” here can either mean Flight Level and/or Altitude?

Comment: That's the part that doesn't make sense @VolkanEroğlu.

Comment: I didn't want to mention flight level/altitude sir, I wanted to mention about transition level and altitude, and they are different things; if you are above the transition level and pass the transition level through below you have to set QNH however when you pass the transition altitude through above you have to set QNE. So I want to ask this; definition include the transition level but not transition altitude. What are your thoughts? @Dean F.

Comment: @GdD which part doesn't make sense, please explain it

Comment: Since the Altitude (Pressure or True) to convert from Altitude MSL to Flight Level in the US is standardized at 18,000 feet MSL, the only transition level I have heard, used or read back has been the altitude required to transit through or above an airspace. For example, ATC has cleared me to transition the DFW B, West to East, at 2000 feet MSL directly over the center of the airfield. Considering the amount and kind of traffic at the airfield, they were gracious to allow the transition. But, they were sticklers about keeping the vertical and lateral position precise.

Comment: I see sir, thanks for your explanation, I get it what you meant @DeanF.

Answer (score 1):

The word “level” is used to refer to Flight Level (or Pressure Altitude). It can (and probably is in this case) also infer the word Altitude (or True Altitude). They are sometimes used interchangeably. Though, by strict definition, they are not the same.

In the US, QNH (Transition Altitude), QNE (Transition Level), and QFE (Transition Height) are not widely used much outside of the military. Instead, the term Lowest Usable Flight Level is substituted. The word “Transition” itself is commonly used to refer to passage through an area. The process to transition the Transition Layer between the Transition Altitude and the Transition Level is standardized for all flights and airspaces.

The Flight Level is the altitude standardized at an altimeter barometric pressure setting of 29.92 inches of mercury. That allows all aircraft to fly at a standardized altimeter adjustment. In theory, this should avoid confusion caused by aircraft flying at different Indicated Altitudes but the same actual True Altitude due to different Kollsman Window settings. All aircraft in the US are to adjust their altimeters and fly using Flight Levels at and above 18,000 feet MSL. Above this Flight Level, precise Absolute Altitude is not necessary.

The following was taken from the FAA-H-8083-16B, Instrument Procedures Handbook, 2017 (IPH)

[image]

Comment: So you say that although transition level and transition altitude different levels and definition include just transition level; transition altitude is also included by definition right? @Dean F.

Comment: @VolkanEroğlu - Pardon me. Would you rephrase the question, please?

Comment: Actually I get my answer above with your explanation about how it works in the US system.

Comment: @VolkanEroğlu - The pure definitions of Transition Altitude and Transition Level are listed in https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Transition_Altitude/Level#Fixed_Transition_Level .   In standard practice, the wording is often used nonstandardly to mean something else. Transition is commonly used as the term to mean passing through. Right or wrong, it is very common in the US. Then again, you will also hear some pilots incorrectly refer to Flight Levels below FL180.

Comment: @VolkanEroğlu - Oh, good. Glad to hear it.